# Selecting unique line problems

Tags: python, lines, records

My head is like a bomb right now, I can't understand what's wrong here?

```
config = open('s1','r').read().splitlines()
new = open('s2','r').read().splitlines()

for clean1 in config:
    x = clean1.split(" ")
for clean2 in new
    x2 = clean2.split(" ")
    if x[0] in x2[0]:
        print x[0] + " already exists."
        break
    if x[0] not in x2[0]:
        print x[0] + " is new."
        break
```

Let me explain:

In the file s1 we got:

```
192.168.1.1 test test
192.168.1.2 test test
```

In the file s2 we got:

```
192.168.1.1 test test
192.168.1.2 test test
192.168.1.3 test test
```

Regarding to this condition:

```
    if x[0] in x2[0]:
        print x[0] + " already exists."
        break
    if x[0] not in x2[0]:
        print x[0] + " is new."
        break
```

The results must be:

```
 192.168.1.1 already exists.
 192.168.1.2 already exists.
 192.168.1.3 is new.
```

But the results are:

```
 192.168.1.1 already exists.
 192.168.1.2 is new.
```

I want a solution for this problem, if you can help me.

**Important notice:**

Do not give me a solution with set() or any kind of library which find unique records. I want a classic-solution.

Comment: The most obvious fault is that the first two pairs of strings (x[0], x2[0]) you compare are 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1) , (192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2). See if you can figure out why that bombs.

Comment: What is a "classic-solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s1 = open('s1', 'r').readlines()
>>> s2 = open('s2', 'r').readlines()

>>> s1Codes = [x.split()[0] for x in s1]
>>> s2Codes = [x.split()[0] for x in s2]

>>> newCodes = [code for code in s2Codes if code not in s1Codes]
>>> print (newCodes)

192.168.1.3
```

Or if you would like to stick to something similar to your solution:

```
>>> s1 = open('s1', 'r').readlines()
>>> s2 = open('s2', 'r').readlines()

>>> s1Codes = [x.split()[0] for x in s1]
>>> s2Codes = [x.split()[0] for x in s2]

>>> for code in s2Codes:
...     if code in s1Codes:
...         print(code + " already exists")
...     else:
...         print(code + " is a new code")

192.168.1.1 already exists
192.168.1.2 already exists
192.168.1.3 is a new code
```

However, as others have stated, the use of `set()` would be ideal here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare unique keys from File 1 with file 2 ,  you could use a python dictionary.

```
m = {}
for line in s1:
    key = line.strip().split(' ')[0]
    if key not in m:
        m[key] = ''

for line in s2:
    key = line.strip().split(' ')[0]
    if key in m:
        # Found key 
        print key + "  Already exists"
    else:
        print key + "  is new"
```

Also another easy way would be to use a set(). This is also a pythonic way of leveraging set logic built into python

```
s1_set = set([line.strip().split(' ')[0] for line in s1])
s2_set = set([line.strip().split(' ')[0] for line in s2])

for key in s1_set.intersection(s2_set): print key + "  Already exists"

#For missing keys
if len(s1_set) > len(s2_set):
    for key in s1_set - s2_set : print key + "  is new"
else:
    for key in s2_set - s1_set : print key + "  is new"
```

Comment: Just pointing this out, OP said they didn't want a set (why not  I don't know,it's a good suggestion)

Comment: Because the OP doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: @paisanco  True,  I wasn't sure myself. But I added it as I  felt set logic was more straight forward for this case.

Comment: Yes I upvoted you anyway because what you wrote made sense.

Comment: OP doesn't want `set()` because OP is doing homework.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with dictionary is the best way.
set() looks like an obvious solution, but it is slower than dict() because dict() stores its entries using hashes.
So, for your need, if you are not going to use your algorithm for big amount of data (like it seems from example files), use list comprehension as shown above, else, use dictionary.
I would not use operator in, but dict.has_key() instead, but that's only my style. Speed should not differ.

Sets are not really supposed to be used with strings, but people do it all the time. :D

Now some additions:

```
Correct! set() also uses hash table.
set() is implemented as a dictionary without values, using only keys.
Nearly exactly what we would do if we use dict() for duplicate detection.
As set() doesn't even support indexing (element order changing according to hashtable),
its natural use would be for stuff such as our question.
Yes, set() should be faster, but it is not.
I can proove it. Try this:
# python -m timeit -s "s = set(range(10**7))" "5*10**6 in s"
2.7: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.161 usec per loop
2.5: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.163 usec per loop

# python -m timeit -s "d = dict.fromkeys(range(10**7))" "5*10**6 in d"
2.7: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.144 usec per loop
2.5: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.133 usec per loop 

We measure here how much time is needed per loop for "in" operator in nearly worst case.
The numbers before results stands for Python 2.7 on Cygwin and Python 2.5 native. That's my config.
I saw more drastic results, on other computers and/or systems where "in dict()" takes 0.0xxx usec, while "in set()" is stil over 0.15xx usec.
I don't know why this difference in speed.
When set() was first added to Python, it was almost a copy-paste of dict() code. It even used dummy values internally.
Not to mention Set() from module sets (Python 2.3 till 2.6 (deprecated)), which actually USES dictionaries.
Now, set() takes somewhat less memory than dict() with dummy values (as we would use), but, obviously, its search is slower.

But regarding the original question this discussion is really unnecessary.
As far as I can tell Brian is comparing two /etc/hosts like files and lists are more than enough for that.
I experienced the speed dilemma and just mentioned my discovery on Stack Overflow for future notice.

This is a trick I found here for solving the problem of duplicates and can easily be modified to solve Brian's problem:
...
l1 = f.readlines()
...
l2 = f.readlines()
...
found = {} # Duplicate entry checker dict
# Take method pointer out to speed up getting to function:
setdef = found.setdefault
# You can construct new list containing old and new entries with no duplicates,
# while keeping order as much as possible, as this:
no_duplicates = [setdef(x, x) for x in l1+l2 if (x not in found)]
del setdef, found
# Get only new-ones (order of l2 is kept):
old = dict.fromkeys(l1)
setdef = old.setdefault
del l1 # If you do not need it any longer and it's really big :D
newcomers = [setdef(x, x) for x in l2 if (x not in old)]
del setdef, old
# Old-ones can be found by reversing places of l1 and l2. (obviously)
# To understand trick with setdefault(), see help(dict.setdefault)
```

If print as you go is really needed, it's easy to switch from list comprehension to real loop.
I am using this algorithm on books with thousands of pages to filter out repeating lines. (headers and footers).
The speed is unbelievable.

```
Why not strings in set()? Well, the name associates to mathematical set, and hashing numbers is easier and faster than hashing strings.
Well dict.has_key() --> :D
```

I am Python 2.5 and 2.7 freak, and I don't like Python 3 at all. So, forgive me pleasefor liking it.
But, as you can see, I am using operator "in" as well. :D

```
P.S. Don't ask me why formatting is as it is. Just correct it if you know how.
```

Comment: Python sets use hashes too, and will be if anything *faster*, not slower, than dictionaries.  `has_key` has been deprecated forever, and doesn't even exist in modern Python.  And I'm not sure why you think sets aren't supposed to be used with strings.

Comment: set() is in fact a dictionary with dummy values, using only keys.

Comment: I am editing my post to answer to you. It's too long for a comment.

Comment: Editing won't pass. And I am sleeping at the keyboard. I'll answer you tomorrow.